# Trying to connect to simple mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to work through Essential Linq and am having an issue simply connecting to the supplied `.mdf` file.

I have saved off the file at `C:\DATA\NORTHWND.MDF`. I am using Visual Studio 2013

The code looks like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace LinqToSqlWithoutDesigner
{
    [Table(Name="Customers")]
    class Customer
    {
        [Column]
        public string CustomerID;
        [Column]
        public string City;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataContext db = new DataContext(@"C:\DATA\NORTHWND.MDF");

            var query = from c in db.GetTable<Customer>()
                    where c.City == "London"
                    select new { CustId = c.CustomerID, City = c.City };

            foreach(var cust in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cust);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                      AttachDbFilename=c:\data\northwind.mdf;
                      Integrated Security=True;
                      Connect Timeout=30;
                      User Instance=True";
DataContext db = new DataContext(connectionString);
```

But I always get the error :

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here was the string which allowed me to connect to the MDF file

```
DataContext db = new DataContext(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;
                                   Integrated Security=true;
                                   AttachDbFileName=C:\DATA\NORTHWND.MDF");
```

More information about LocalDB can be found at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you do not have SQL Server Express on your computer or the requested network interface protocol is not activated.

For a `.mdf` file you NEED to have an up and running SQL Server

Comment: My understanding is that when doing it like this it simply creates a sql server express instance on the fly.  I am able to open the file in Sever Explorer just fine

Comment: no this understanding is not correct... You have to install sqlexpress

Comment: @Dalupus if you only have .mdf file you can't do any thing with it

Comment: @swe. What do you think

Comment: sql server express comes bundled with visual studio I thought?  I can connect to the database fine inside of server explorer in visual studio

Comment: so the next point to look at is the protocols. i never used the "coming with" sqlexpress. standard sqlexpress has tcp/ip-protocol deactivated. so you should ask for another protocol in your connection string or activate tcpip

Comment: .... and to use the `AttachDbFileName=...` feature, this **must be** an Express edition!  No other editions support this feature

Comment: I posted the connect string which allowed me to connect.   I did not have to install or startup sql server express as a version of it comes bundled with Visual Studio.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

the catalog name does not exist in your connection string

add to connectionString:

```
catalog=yourDbName
```

NB: You can not connect directly to an MDF file.

If the database does not exist in your database server you need to use the .mdf file and the .ldf file.

Then use your connection string and add the catalog name as i mentioned